# getClientOriginalName() -> to www convention?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having problems with some of the files updloaded by users, because some images have spaces, weir characters etc.. is there any way to trim/bring to a www convention (so that any explorer read the url correctly?

The problem is here

```
$name = date('Ymd'). $new_event->id. '-' .$i->getClientOriginalName();
```

One solution would be to put hhmmss plus some random, but not sure if its a good idea, or better to keep the image name.

```
if($request->hasFile('images')){

    $destinationPath = public_path('/img/events');

        foreach($request->images as $i){

        $name = date('Ymd'). $new_event->id. '-' .$i->getClientOriginalName();

        $img = Image::make($i->getRealPath());      $img->resize(600, null, function ($constraint) {            $constraint->aspectRatio();             $constraint->upsize();      });          $img->save($destinationPath.'/'.$name);


        $new_multimedia = new EventMultimedia();        $new_multimedia->event_id
= $new_event->id;       $new_multimedia->url = $name;       $new_multimedia->reference_table = 'events';

        $new_multimedia->save();    }   

}
```

Comment: Slugify the name `str_slug()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can slugify it.

```
$name = date('Ymd'). $new_event->id. '-' .str_slug($i->getClientOriginalName(), '-');
```

Comment: Thats what my comment says, OP should see my comment and delete the question because it attracts one line answers like this.

Comment: thank you, I cant delete the question now, but hopefully is interesting for others